# When adding dynamical image src i get Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './image.png'

Tags: html, reactjs, image

I've been trying to add upload and then display some pictures. Upload part is all fine i think.

I tried This:

```
<Card.Img
  variant='left'
  src={require(`../../images/${image_url}`)}
  width='100px'
  style={{objectFit:"cover"}}
/>
```

Also This:

```
<Card.Img
  variant='left'
  src={require('../../images/'+ image_url)}
  width='100px'
  style={{objectFit:"cover"}}
/>
```

When i write src={require('../../images/image.jpg')} it works just fine.

Expected result is to display the images.

Comment: your image is not a Node module. Just point to the actual image URL as exposed by the server, there is absolutely zero reason to try to bundle images in.

Comment: how can i do that? And what do you mean by "bundle images in" could you further explain it? I'm new to this.

Comment: You put your images in a normal static asset dir, which your server exposes. Then you just use a normal image URL like you would if React never existed. So not ```src={require(`../../images/${image_url}`)}``` but ```src={`/images/${image_url}`}``` or whatever your static image directory is exposed as.

Comment: In my case image_url is just a string "image.jpg". I'm attaching file names to cards and then combining them with base url (../../images/) thats why i'm so confused that i get this error. When i use src={`/images/${image_url}`} images won't show at all

Comment: How should `require` resolve such a request? Turn it into a base64? Thing is, unlike JS or JSON, requiring an image file makes no sense. This is why node exposes things such as the filesystem API so you can read and act on arbitrary data like that. But the solution mentioned above is better - create a public directory that you can just point the output too and load from instead of 'including' it in your base code.